# iOS video player app with short skip forward/backward feature

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, video

I like the feature that YouTube has in their mobile app where you can double-tap the left and right edges of the player and it'll skip ahead slightly in that direction. Netflix has a similar feature that I also like.

Both the scrubbing feature and the tiny player buttons in the iOS default Videos UI just feel awful in comparison.

Is there an alternative video player that has a similar "do this simple action to nudge the active timestamp in the video a couple seconds" feature?

I am using an iPhone SE running iOS 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [VLC for iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/app/vlc-for-mobile/id650377962).

The app has host of features (just like the Desktop counterpart). You can simply swipe to skip back/forward.